# How to get error from custom validator in html?

Tags: angular, customvalidator

I have such form in ts:

```
this._logInForm = _formBuilder.group<ILoginModel>({
      userName: ['', {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }],
      password: ['', {
        validators: [PASSWORD_VALIDATOR(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{5,}$/)],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }
      ]
    });
```

Validator code:

```
function PASSWORD_VALIDATOR(correctPattern: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return ((control: AbstractControl): { incorrectPassword: RegExp } | null => {
    if (!correctPattern.test(control.value)) {
      return { incorrectPassword: correctPattern };
    }
    return null;
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="login__validation-error" *ngIf="passwordControl.errors!.incorrectPassword && passwordControl.touched">Password must be longer than 5 symbols and must contain 1 digit, 1 lowercase and 1 uppercase letter</p>
```

So, it gives me a compile error: "Property 'incorrectPassword' does not exist on type 'ValidatorsModel'."

I understand that, but how can i touch this error in html? Are there any variants except writing specific directive for custom validators and work with it?

Comment: What's `ValidatorsModel`? Are you using `ng-stack`? If so, you should make it explicit in your question, I don't thing your issue is directly related to Angular itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ts Code

```
function PASSWORD_VALIDATOR(correctPattern: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
    let urlRegEx: RegExp = new RegExp('/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{5,}$/');
       
        if (control.value && !control.value.match(urlRegEx)) {
            return {
                pattern: 'Password must be longer than 5 symbols and must contain 1 digit, 1 lowercase and 1 uppercase letter'
            };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
```

Html Code

```
<p class="login__validation-error" *ngIf="_logInForm .controls['password'].errors.pattern">Password must be longer than 5 symbols and must contain 1 digit, 1 lowercase and 1 uppercase letter</p>
```

Form Change:

```
 password: ['', PASSWORD_VALIDATOR('password')], // password means formControlName
```